# Launch Teams chat with particular contact using msteams URI scheme

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm able to open Teams chat with a specified contact using 'sip:example@emailaddress.com' but 'msteams:example@emailaddress.com' only opens the application; it does not open chat with the specified individual.

Is there, or will there be, a scheme which allows for opening chat with an individual using the 'msteams:' uri similar to 'skype:example@emailaddress.com'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported for Microsoft Teams but it's on our roadmap.

Comment: This will do it  <a href="MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=username@domain.com">Teams Chat</a>

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer**
try this   `<a href="MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=username@domain.com">Teams Chat</a>`

This will open a private conversation with the user in ms teams

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Find the Chat deeplink, and embed elsewhere.

Example: With one or more users can be specified.

Example: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow

The query parameters are:

```
users The comma-separated list of user IDs representing the participants of the chat. The user performing the action is always included as a participant. The User ID field currently only supports the Azure AD UserPrincipalName (typically an email address).
topicName An optional field for chat's display name, in the case of a chat with 3 or more users. If this field is not specified, the chat's display name will be based on the names of the participants.
message An optional field for the message text that you want to insert into the current user's compose box while the chat is in a draft state.
```

**Note that the link will only open a chat if the users are in your tenant. For federated users it will only open if you previously had a chat window with them.**