# Multi-line message via deeplinking in MS-Teams

Tags: javascript, html, deep-linking

```
<a href="MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=<user@domain.com>&message=Hello \nWorld">Teams</a>
```

The task is to have a multi-line messages on chat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch Teams chat with particular contact using msteams URI scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995622/launch-teams-chat-with-particular-contact-using-msteams-uri-scheme)

Comment: According to an answer to the question yours is a duplicate of, `message` should be URL-encoded, which means `\n` should be `%0A`, a space should be `%20`, and so on.